# VB - Change a field id if a string in another field is "transfer"

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

So i have a database with a col called accountid and i also have a col called narrative, what i would like to do is. if fields in col narrative = "transfer" change the accountid to 2001. i want this to happen on the click of a button in a form.

i have tryed to add the code below but i get syntax near the keyword "set"

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: i need to try the code below but don't know where to put this in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query for that is

```
update your_table
set accountid = 2001
where narrative = 'transfer'
```

Comment: But how do i put this into visual basic form application ?. so it does it on button press.

Comment: be very grateful for this help.